# How to add source and target in callactivity using java approach

Tags: activiti

In activiti how to add call activity parameters.

```
CallActivity callactivity=new CallActivity();
callactivity.setId("callactivity1");
callactivity.setCalledElement("dummy");
```

I am not finding any resource of how to add call activity source and target expression for sharing data between processes java code.

```
<extensionElements>
   <activiti:in source="name" target="name"></activiti:in>
</extensionElements>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected List<IOParameter> inParameters = new ArrayList<IOParameter>();
protected List<IOParameter> outParameters = new ArrayList<IOParameter>();

IOParameter io=new IOParameter();
io.setSource("body");
io.setTarget("body");
inParameters.add(io);
callactivity.setInParameters(inParameters);
```